# when to stop reduction in lambda caculus

Tags: lambda-calculus, reduction

I am confused about how the lambda reduction terminates.For example，the number 2 is written as

```
\xy.xxy
```

Why shouldn't we continue to apply beta substitution rule and make it like

```
\xy.(x)xy
＝＞\ab.axy
＝＞\b.yx
＝＞y
```

This is clearly wrong.But i don't know why.Can anyone help me?thx a lot!

Answer (score 1):

If you're having trouble making substitutions, I recommend you use fully expanded forms

```
\xy.xxy
```

is **not**

```
\xy.(x)xy
```

it is

```
λx. λy. (x x) y
```

which can be eta-reduced to

`λx. λy. (x x) y
λx. (x x)
λx. x x`

which is in [head normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_normal_form) and cannot be further reduced

beta substitution wasn't necessary in this particular problem